# ST_Split only on blade

Tags: postgis, st-split

If the geometry input (a line string in my case) crosses over itself, ST_Split is splitting on the crossover as well as the blade. Is that the expected case / is it possible to only split on the blade?

PostGIS:  3.3.2
Postgres: 15.1

ST_Split does not support M, but i needed a time dimension so put it in Z (yes this is **very bad** and has unintended consequences) it would be handy if split passed through M values and had an option not to cut itself.

I can get the desired outcome with some aggregates.

```sql
with fragments as ( 
    select  st_dump(st_split(st_makeline(point order by ts), (select st_union(wkb_geometry) from checkpoints))) frag
    from track 
    where activity_id = 101)
, part as (
select 
    (frag).geom line,
    c_start.name start_name,
    c_end.name end_name, 
    sum(case when c_start.name is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by (frag).path[1]) as segment_partition
from fragments
left outer join checkpoints c_start on ST_DWithin(st_startpoint((frag).geom)::geography, c_start.wkb_geometry::geography, 0.1)
left outer join checkpoints c_end on ST_DWithin(st_endpoint((frag).geom)::geography, c_end.wkb_geometry::geography, 0.1)
)
, segments as (
select 
    st_makeline(line) segment,
    to_timestamp(st_z(st_startpoint(st_makeline(line)))) start_ts,
    to_timestamp(st_z(st_endpoint(st_makeline(line)))) end_ts,
    (array_agg(distinct start_name) filter (where start_name is not null))[1] start_segment,
    (array_agg(distinct end_name) filter (where end_name is not null))[1] end_segment,
    segment_partition
from part
group by segment_partition
)
select
    segment,
    st_length(ST_Force2D(segment)::geography) length_m,
    start_ts,
    end_ts,
    end_ts - start_ts duration,
    start_segment,
    end_segment,
    segment_partition segment_order
from segments;
```

[image: QGIS output of ST_Split showing the blades as red lines]

Simple WKT version:

[image]

Red is the blade, st_split returns 4 parts.

```sql
select st_dump(st_split(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(13 10,12 11,11 12,10 13,9 14,10 15,11 15,11 16,12 16,13 14,12 13,9 5)'),
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(8 12, 11 6)')));
```

I should mention I have solved the problem in a somewhat more logical way then posted above without putting time into Z. Now it is just really a question of is that an expected output for st_split()?

Comment: Is your input linestring valid?

Comment: Could you add simple examples of a blade and a linestring as WKT?

Comment: @user30184 example added

Comment: @IanTurton as far as I can tell, I also see the same outcome with a simple WKT example, added above.

Comment: did you run `st_isValid` on them to check?

Comment: @IanTurton Yes all inputs return true for st_isValid

Is it possible for something like `select st_makeline(point) from track where activity_id = 222;` to silently return a not valid line? apart from null?

Comment: Of course, see https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity

Comment: `st_isValid()` && `st_isSimple()` is what I needed to check.

I found a reference to it in Version 1.4 of the PostGIS manual:
4.2.5. Ensuring OpenGIS compliancy of geometries:
"As such, many PostGIS methods require, or more accurately, assume that geometries that are operated on are both simple and valid"

https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ch04.html#OGC_Validity

It would appear that st_split() is one of the PostGIS methods that assume valid and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`st_split()` requires a Valid and Simple Geometry.

Using a GPS trail (or any linestring) that crosses over itself does not meet the requirements.

https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity

https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/postgis_usage.html#OGC_Validity

> 4.1.5. Geometry Validation
>
> PostGIS is compliant with the Open Geospatial Consortium’s (OGC)
> OpenGIS Specifications. As such, many PostGIS methods require, or more
> accurately, assume that geometries that are operated on are both
> simple and valid.